# Understanding Cantor diagonalisation in binary

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

Until now I have studied and understood Cantor's proof. My problem comes when looking at binary representation:

```
integer    binary representation    encoding for diag proof
1          1                        10000...
2          10                       01000...
3          11                       11000...
4          100                      00100...
5          101                      10100...
```

So far so good. We have now represented all integers uniquely by their binary representation.

Now let's apply the diagonalisation and generate the number K:

```
K = 0011111111111111....
```

I know that after 1 and 2, the representation will be 1 because we move right faster than the 1's do.

So according to Cantor, this binary number will not be present in our enumeration, so what is this number?

```
K = 0*1 + 0*2 + 1*4 + 1*8 + ...
K = 4 * (1 + 2 + 4 + ... )
K = 4 * (3 + K)
K = -4
```

Clearly something funny is happening here, I have two questions:

- Has this demonstrated a binary number not present in our enumeration? If not, why not?
- How have we enumerated a negative binary number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$K$ is not a real number, since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n$ does not converge. So no, you did not find an integer which is missing from your enumeration. Your proof for $K=-4$ is similar to the "proof" that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac{1}{12}$ in that both apply facts about convergent series to a non-convergent series.

Usually if you write down this kind of diagonal encoding you're trying to prove that the *reals* are uncountable. So you should encode the reals (or at least a nicely encodable subset like $[0,1)$), not the integers. If you do that, the string $a_1a_2a_3\dots$ encodes the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n2^{-n}$, which does converge, since its dominated by the convergent geometric series. So there you *will* actually find a not yet encoded real number, since the series then actually corresponds to a number.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense about the value of K. The question still stands though, have we not generated a binary representation that by definition is not in our enumerable list? What is the key difference between this and the interval [0,1)?

Comment: @Matt, you have an infinite binary string not in your original enumeration. But the "binary numbers" you're enumerating correspond to the finite binary strings, not the infinite ones. As it turns out, you could apply this argument to the set of infinite binary strings to show they aren't countable.

Comment: @Matt, Izaak van Dongen already gave a pretty good answer. But about the difference between this and $[0,1)$: Every binary string actually does correspond to a real number in $[0,1)$, if you do the encoding correctly. As Izaak van Dongen said, this is not the case for your encoding of the integers, which is why your argument fails.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen As far as I can tell these are infinite binary strings, for example 1 corresponds to a single 1 followed by infinitely many 0's. In fact, we can allow aribitrarily many 1's in our representation too. I can see that here that K = 0011111... corresponds to exactly the same number as K = 111111... but only in the same way that we have problems representing a decimal representation of 0.000....002 and 0.000...003

Comment: @Matt, OK, I should have said "binary strings that are eventually all $0$s". This set is countable. The set of "binary strings that are eventually either all $0$s or all $1$s" is also countable. If you try use a diagonal argument on this set, the string you get will necessarily alternate between $0$ and $1$ infinitely often. The set of all infinite binary strings is not countable.

Comment: ooooh right, so you're saying that I have created a binary string here but my list doesn't actually contain all binary strings? But it seems that K must exist as we must have the sequence (```0*1 + 0* 2 + 1 *2```,  ```0*1 + 0* 2 + 1*2 + 1*4```, ```0*1 + 0* 2 + 1*2 + 1*4 + 1*8```, etc.)

Comment: @Matt, yes, as it stands, your list only contains the infinite binary sequences that are all $0$s from some point on. Your $K$ does not have this property, so there is no contradiction. The fact that there are strings in your sequence with arbitrarily many $1$s at the end does not imply that $K$ is in your sequence.